# How to minimize a specific window in a remote VM using powershell - For Automation test suit

Tags: javascript, powershell, virtual-machine, webdriver-io

I am wondering if there is a command in **Powershell** to minimize a specific window (Eg: notepad || cmd.exe) in a **remote** machine.
I have tried the following commands, these worked in my local machine but don't seem to be for remote Vms.

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).MinimizeAll()


Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/690865/616288

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/Nora-Ballard/11240204 has Powershell code that will do window manipulation by `MainWindowHandle`, which you can get from `Get-Process`.